# Presenting a webpage from raspberry pi

Tags: chromium

I'm a newbie on raspberry pi, and I want to hack it for the office I'm working for.

My desired achievement is connecting the pi to a tv then booting into chromium and showing a reveal.js[1] presentation.

I did whole work, but, it seems like raspberry pi can't handle that much data. transition effects on reveal.js are not smooth. I mean it seems like 1 frame per second and it seems terrible.

Is there anyway to boost the browsers speed to make it seem more smooth? eg. lightweight browser etc.

thanks for any advice.

[1] http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/

Answer (score 2):

I have a pi running what looks like a flightboard at an airport on a 42" LCD TV (It's a loadboard for freight logistics).  It boots into Chromium in kiosk mode and runs on an Arch Linux/LXDE setup.  In my experience, the faster, lightweight browsers couldn't do the heavy lifting I needed code wise.  I could be wrong.

Overclocking will give you the most dramatic increase in speed.  There's lots of guides on how to do that.  Limiting your display resolution will give the pi a break as well, if that works in your scenario.  In my case, 720p was necessary.

The main issue I have with mine is that it freezes and becomes unresponsive maybe once a week.  Also, Chromium runs out of memory with an ugly "He's Dead, Jim!" message.  I do make XHR requests every 30 seconds or so though to keep the display up to date.  This could be an issue for a work environment.  I gave the department using it a remote that can restart chrome at the press of a button and showed them how to reboot the monitor if it was unresponsive.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience. it will be helpful for sure.

Answer (score 1):

In general part of the problem that you're experiencing is that screen updates to the Pi are slow because it's a framebuffer device. You may get better performance if you lower the resolution using [config.txt](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#Video_mode_options).

Also, it may be worth looking into the [official optimised browser](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5535).